# Why my baseboard heater won’t turn with new thermostat?

Tags: electrical, heating, thermostat, heater, baseboard

I have a pair of electromod basement heater. The label on each of them show them show 750/1000W. Power supply to this is 240V

I am trying to replace the old manual thermostat with a progrmabale one. I bought Aube TH106 and installed it. It turns on fine and set the target temperature around 6 degrees more than the current temperature.

However the heater is not turning on. The thermostat is supposed to work with minimum 2Amp.

Now thinking baseboard heater may not be working, I put the old thermostat back and the heater runs fine.  With the new thermostat I also checked if power is coming to the heater with a voltage tester and it’s positive. I don’t have a multimeter right now with me

What could be wrong here? Any idea ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What do you mean the "thermostat is not turning on", if "it turns on fine"? And, when there's trouble is the thermostat able to be programmed?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the heater! Thanks for the correction

Comment: Thanks, and props for editing your question rather than thinking your comment will be enough. That said, getting a voltage reading on the heater when the thermostat thinks it's "on" will be illuminational.

Comment: I am picking up a digital multimeter tomorrow ..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be abandoned without enough details in the original version of the question to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a pair of 700/1000w heaters. I know of quite a few thermostats that won't switch over 1.5kw maybe your new thermostat is like those. Check it's maximum handling wattage.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind would be a possible wiring issue. If the old stat works properly that can only lead to one thing. Improper wiring on new stat, or a bad stat right out of the box. Believe me when I say this, its more common than one would think. 
 I would double check the wiring. Double check the programming. If all that checks to be normal and within the manufacturers specs. Then that would leave one to reasonably believe the stat is bad OR incompatible with your system. I know this isn't a lot of help to you. 
 I have seen many cases where components and parts have been DOA right out of the box.